# How to split date and time from a string in Python 3?

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have the following text `2017-01-20T21:55:00Z`

I want the text to look like this `2017-01-20` whilst also having a separate text that reads `21:55`

I am using Python 3.

Comment: PLEASE NO SHOUTING. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: hint: You can use `str.split` / `str.rsplit`.

Comment: im not exactly to sure how to use str.split ?

Comment: `first, second = s.split('T')` where `s` is your string, or `first, sep, second = s.partition('T')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code.

```
string="2017-01-20T21:55:00Z"

print string[0:10]
```

Output:

> 2017-01-20

```
string="2017-01-20T21:55:00Z"

print string[11:19]
```

Output:

> 21:55:00

Comment: if your are working with date in python it is more precise to use all date function instead of the string.

Comment: This was very helpful however how can I use this to also use the other half of the text. By which I mean your code prints `2017-01-20` however I also need this `21:55:00` using your method how will I go about doing this.